# I need command line for Linux and MacOS

Tags: java, linux, macos

So I know a command lines that I need For windows:

```
cd src
java -cp . mazesolver.SolverCode
```

Now I need what those lines will be in:
**Mac OS and Linux**

Comment: no difference, will be the same, as long as java is installed and configured

Comment: Ok, thanks! But is 'cd <folder>' the same

Comment: yes, cd <folder> is also same

Comment: Ok, Thank you dkb!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the same thing. Just be careful to don't use functions which only work on a specified os.